# Exporting images from image collection in Google Earth Engine - user memory limit exceeded

Tags: javascript, export, google-earth-engine, landsat

I'm fairly new to GEE, and I'm trying to process some imagery, then download the results. I need to mask about 30 years of Landsat data to isolate different land cover types, remove clouds, and calculate vegetation indices. Then, I need to export these data to do further analyses in R. I've managed to do all of the masking and calculating vegetation indices, but when I go to export the data, it gives me the `user memory limit exceeded` error. I tried to only download 1 year of data at a time but got the same error. I'm not sure how to accomplish what I'm doing, which is to do the heavy processing of the data in GEE then export it to do the additional analyses elsewhere. Any recommendations? Code below.

Edit: Added the ROI information as recommended.

````
var l8sr = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterDate('2013-07-01','2018-06-30');
  
//Function to mask forest
var maskForest = function(img){
  var mask = forest.eq(1);
  return img.updateMask(mask);
};

// Function to mask flooded area
var maskFld = function(img){
  var mask = fldpln.eq(1);
  return img.updateMask(mask);
};

// Cloud masking function
var mask = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:cloud_masks');

var mask_fun = mask.landsatSR();

// Create EVI mapping functions
var EVI8 = function(img){
  var evi = img.expression(
  '2.5*((NIR/10000-RED/10000)/(NIR/10000 + 6 * RED/10000 - 7.5 * BLUE/10000 + 1))', {
    'NIR': img.select('B5'),
    'RED': img.select('B4'),
    'BLUE': img.select('B2')
  }).rename('EVI');
return(img.addBands(evi));
};

// Map the forest/savanna/cloud masks and indices to the image collections and select the VI bands
var l8srFldFor = l8sr.map(maskForest).map(maskFld).map(mask_fun).map(EVI8)

// Download images from collection to Drive
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');

var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([[-48.425,-9.577],[-48.036,-8.390]]);

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(l8srFldFor, 'LandsatTiles', 
                {scale: 30, 
                region: roi,
                 type: 'float'});```
````

Comment: How many images would you like to download, in total?

Comment: Ultimately, it's about 380 images. I did try to reduce it to just 1 month's worth, which would be just the 2 images, and I got the same error.

Comment: How did you define your region of interest?

Comment: @JonathanV.Solórzano
I added these two lines:
`roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([[xxxxxxx,xxxxxx],[xxxxxxx,xxxxxxx]])`


`region: roi.getInfo()["coordinates"],`

The xxxxx was the coordinate info for the region of interest. The second line was in the curly brackets in `batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive`

Comment: You could try setting the `region` argument of the `batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive` simply as `roi`.

Comment: @JonathanV.Solórzano I just tried that, and it is still giving me the `user memory limit exceeded` error.

Comment: Then you are probably exceeding the per user memory limit of GEE. However, it will be difficult to replicate the situation without the complete info about the `roi` object. Consider adding it to the OP. That way other users might be able to replicate the problem and find a solution.

Comment: I updated OP to add in ROI information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not applying any spatial filter to the landsat 8 collection. Therefore, the resulting collection is including **every** landsat 8 image acquired from '2013-07-01' to '2018-06-30'. So probably that was causing the `user memory limit exceeded` error. To apply a spatial filter based on your `roi` you should use `filterBounds`.

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([[-48.425,-9.577],[-48.036,-8.390]]);
var l8sr = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterDate('2018-05-01','2018-06-30')
  .filterBounds(roi);
```

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you for the fix!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to download from all over the world?

Comment: Angel: Please use the Comments here

Comment: No. I also added an ROI to the download, but I got the same error. The area I want to download is relatively small (smaller than a single Landsat tile).